# How to handle multiple array filters with Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Not sure when to use computed properties vs watch to display my data. I'm building an app with the PokeAPI, and I want to toggle between Type and Generation to display the pokemon. So far I have a JS file that stores all the pokemon in an array:

```
//pokeData.js
import axios from 'axios'

const allPokes = [];

export default{
    getPokemon(){
        if(allPokes.length === 0){
            for(let i=1; i<=809; i++){
                axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`)
                .then(response => {
                    allPokes.push(response.data);
                    allPokes.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
                });
            }
        }
        return allPokes
    }
}
```

I don't want to repeatedly call 809 Objects from an API, so I call them in the mounted() in my Vue, and want to filter them from there:

```
//Container.vue
//takes two props, 'currentType' and 'currentGen', to use to filter the pokemon

<template>
        <div 
        v-for="(pokemon, index) in allPokemon"
        :key="index">
            <h2>{{ pokemon.name }}</h2>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
import Pokemon from '../pokeData'

export default {
    props: ['currentType', 'currentGen'],
    data(){
        return{
            allPokemon: [],
        }
    },
    mounted(){
            this.allPokemon = Pokemon.getPokemon();
    },
    watch: {
        currentType: function(newType){
            const typePokes = this.allPokemon.filter(pokemon => {
                    if(pokemon.types[0].type.name == newType){
                        return true
                     }
                  this.allPokemon = typePokes  
            });
```

I know this is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it. I know you can use List Rendering as suggested in the official documents, but it doesn't say how to use it for multiple filters. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Replacing-an-Array

Any advice is welcome: how to better cache the initial API call; to use watch or computed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A computed prop is what you need in this situation:

```
computed: {
  filteredPokemons () {
    if (this.currentType) {
      return this.allPokemon.filter(pokemon => pokemon.types[0].type.name == this.currentType)
    }
    if (this.currentGen) {
      // I assumed that a prop is named 'gen', just replace with an actual prop
      return this.allPokemon.filter(pokemon => pokemon.types[0].gen.name == this.currentGen)
    }
    // you didn't mentioned what to show when both currentType and currentGen is empty
    // I assumed it should be an empty array
    return []
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems right, however it doesn't react when the currentType is changed. The currentGen prop will return different sections of the allPokemon array using splice(), and when both currentType and currentGen are empty, it should be the original allPokemon array

Comment: So you claim that 'watch' on currentType triggers and a computed prop don't?

Comment: I have a console.log on watch: currentType and the computed code you suggested. When I change the currentType the console.log fires for the watch property but not the computed one

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference between a computed prop and a watch on a prop. Did you added console.log at the beginning of the computed prop?

Comment: Yes, the code now looks like this: 
```computed: {
        filteredPokemons () {
            if (this.currentType) {
                console.log('hello')
                return this.allPokemon.filter(pokemon => { pokemon.types[0].type.name == this.currentType });
            }```

Comment: No, move console.log outside and before `if`

Comment: did you change `v-for="(pokemon, index) in allPokemon"` to `v-for="(pokemon, index) in filteredPokemons"` ? If a computed prop is not used then it's never calculated even if props are changes that are used in it

Comment: -_- of course, I wasn't calling it. Thanks for your help